# clustring by RSU in veins

Tags: omnet++, veins

I'm going to do fuzzy clustering by RSU in veins.
For this purpose, I first created a module that inherits TraCIDemo11p and incorporated clustering codes in it.
Then I created a method in TraCIDemoRSU11p and I made an object from the clustering class in it, and then called the method of clustering. Of course, I also used " std::cout<<" to  this part ,if this part of the code was executed I noticed.
I ran the program but unfortunately didn't see what I was writing on the " std::cout<<" and realized that this part of my code wasn't running.

I want to know where should I call my clustering class to do the cluster at the beginning of the simulation?

I need your answer to solve my problem
Thanks

Comment: I forgot to say ,I use omnetpp-5.4.1 , veins-4.7.1 , sumo-0.30.0

Comment: My question is answered at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57933719/initialize-method-in-tracidemorsu11p

Comment: Possible duplicate of [initialize method in TraCIDemoRSU11p](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57933719/initialize-method-in-tracidemorsu11p)