# initialize method in TraCIDemoRSU11p

Tags: omnet++, veins

I'm using omnetpp-5.4.1 , veins-4.7.1 , sumo-0.30.0 .I'm going to do fuzzy clustering by RSU in veins.I created a new module called FCM in veins/modules/application/traci and inherited the TraCIDemo11p and wrote the clustering code in it.
Because I want to RSU start clustering,I used the initialize method in the TraCIDemoRSU11p to call the method inside the FMC at the start of work.

```
    void TraCIDemoRSU11p::initialize(int stage) {
    BaseWaveApplLayer::initialize(stage);

    std::cout<<"starting clustering";
    FCM * fcm_clustering;
    fcm_clustering->clustering();


}
```

When I run the program, it is not allowed to run at the start of the program, saying "finish with error" and the program stops running.
What can I do to call the clustering by RSU at the beginning of the simulation?

please help me to solvemy problem.
Thanks.

Comment: To find out if the initialize method was working or not, I cleaned all the code inside the method except the "cout<<" and then ran the program.  When the program was run, after receiving a message coming from the vehicle to the RSU,
RSU did not send a message to the vehicles and the "cou<<" I wrote inside the method will not be printed.Is it right to use initialize method?
Where should I call clustering to perform clustering by RSU?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have defined a pointer `fcm_clustering` but you **didn't initialize it**. Therefore an attempt to use it ends up with memory violation.
Try to create `FCM` object, for example:

```
FCM * fcm_clustering = new FCM();
```

Comment: Thanks for your guide
Unfortunately, it makes the same error and stops the simulation

Comment: So in your `omnetpp.ini` set `debug-on-errors=true`, and run simulation in Debug mode - an example is [here](https://docs.omnetpp.org/tutorials/tictoc/part2/#23-debugging). The simulation will stop on the line that causes an error.

Comment: Thank you very much, your guide on defined a pointer helped me a lot
I do what you said carefully again, and my code was executed, and I realized where the code was right and where the code was wrong with the help of "cout<<"